# How to play Call of Duty World at War without having to put in the disc?

Tags: call-of-duty-world-at-war

This is the Games for Windows version, and I don't like how it makes my computer loud when I have the disc in it.

Comment: Buy a digital copy? It's available [on Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/10090/). You seem to keep asking very similar questions, and they're not getting any better.

Comment: My cousin did it for me b4 but got a new pc but how do i do it

Comment: Go on Steam site, or other digital store of your choice, enter credit card details, purchase, download, install and play game.

Comment: There's no legal way make the retail version of the game start without putting the disc in, sorry. Buying the game again for the very high Steam price just to play it without a disc would be a waste of money.

Comment: Are you sure it's just the disk making the noise?

Comment: Disks always make noise... Including my fans for some reason when I just built my pc

Comment: @oStarZ No, drives make noise, disks spin in the drives. Fans increase speed when demand is put on the system, this allows your pc to cool efficiently. Also I agree with TZHX, just get a digital copy. Games for Windows is shutting down soon so you would not be able to continue to play the game anyway.

Comment: FFS. **"Games for Windows" is not shutting down.** There's nothing *to* shut down.

Comment: "Games for Windows" is not the same thing as "Games for Windows Live".

Comment: I feel like this might be closable, or at least, should be put on hold.

Comment: I feel like the people who downvoted this question have no idea of their legal rights.

Answer (score 1):

There is no legitimate way to play or install the disc version of the game without using the game DVD.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible.

You are legitimately allowed to make backups of your purchased media.
Take your Purchased game and do the following:

```
1. Insert the DISC
2. Move all the files across to your computer
3. Download IMGBurn to turn your Files into an .ISO
4. Download a virtual Mount software like PowerISO etc
5. Attach your .ISO to the virtual mount
6. Load up the game as usual and enter in your Key Code
7. Play.
```

This does work. Everything is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that this works (I did this just today on Windows 10 v22H2):

- Install Alcohol 120% Free Edition from [here](https://www.alcohol-soft.com/designzoo/downloada120fe.html) (NOTE: My Avast antivirus blocked it, I checked it with VirusTotal and it seems OK. I think the AV blocked it because, at the end of the installation, you have the option to activate 3 virtual CD/DVD-ROM devices at the price of sharing your IP for some bandwidth sharing service. I chose **NO** at that option)
- Create an image of your DVD using the SecuROM profile. Save it in .MDF/.MDS format (and **NOT** ISO)
- After you have the image, mount it using the included virtual device, then start the single player game. It works!
- Optional: I didn't want to leave Alcohol 120% installed, so I uninstalled it, and installed DAEMON Tools Lite, then mounted the image using a SCSI virtual device. That worked perfectly too

Comment: Hi gog. This is basically the same as one of the existing answers, but using different software. Please read through existing answers before posting your own, so we don't get duplicates. And please take the [Tour] to familiarize yourself with our platform. Welcome to Arqade!

Comment: @Joachim negative. This game has the SecuROM copy protection, and creating an ISO that contains all the files on the DVD by simply copying them is NOT the same as making a 1:1 copy using a software such as Alcohol 120%, which also copies subchannel data. You can verify my answer vs the josh.thomson one: the single player game will NOT start, asking you to insert the correct DVD and restart the application.

Comment: Yeah, you're right; I have faced those problems myself as well, actually. My apologies. I'll remove my comment (I still recommend you take our [Tour], though :).